# How is this recurring decimal multiplication getting an accurate result

Tags: java, floating-point

How does (1 / 3) * 3 = 1.00000000000000000000, is it being rounded from 0.9999...?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double numerator = 1.0;
    double denominator = 3.0;
    double result = numerator / denominator;
    System.out.printf("1 / 3 = %f \n", result);
    double multiplied = result * 3;
    System.out.printf("3 * (1/3) = %.20f \n", multiplied);
    System.out.format("%.14f", 1.0/3.0 * 3);
}
```

results

```
1 / 3 = 0.333333 
3 * (1/3) = 1.00000000000000000000 
1.00000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like `1/3.0` cannot be accurately represented by a double in Java, it is also not possible to accurately represent `3 * 1.0/3.0`. The closest number to it that *can* accurately be represented by a `double` is `1`.
You're lucky.

You can convert the 64 bits of a double to a long with `Double.doubleToLongBits`. This shows you that the following 3 double expressions all have the same representation in the bits of a double:

```
System.out.println(Double.doubleToLongBits(1.0 / 3.0 * 3));
System.out.println(Double.doubleToLongBits(1d));
System.out.println(Double.doubleToLongBits(0.99999999999999999d));
```

Shows:

```
4607182418800017408
4607182418800017408
4607182418800017408
```

Comment: Is it common for numbers to be inaccurately rounded with doubles in Java? Is it better to use a library if using exponents and division arithmetic a lot?

Comment: It is necessary for repeating fractions to be inaccurately rounded in any positional numeral system. There are numbers that can be accurately represented in one base (base 10 for example, take number 0.1) that are a repeating fraction in another (for example, the base-10 number 0.1 is a repeating fraction in base-2). You can use BigDecimal if you want to stay in base-10, but it will be much slower. However 1/3 is a repeating fraction in base-10 *and* base-2.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your program to show exact values, without output rounding. `BigDecimal` can be very useful for probing the behavior of `double`.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double numerator = 1.0;
    double denominator = 3.0;
    double result = numerator / denominator;
    System.out.printf("1 / 3 = %s \n", new BigDecimal(result));
    double multiplied = result * 3;
    System.out.printf("3 * (1/3) = %s \n", new BigDecimal(multiplied));
    BigDecimal exactMultiplied = new BigDecimal(result).multiply(new BigDecimal(3));
    System.out.println(exactMultiplied);
    BigDecimal upError = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(exactMultiplied);
    System.out.printf("Error on round up %s \n", upError);
    BigDecimal downError = exactMultiplied.subtract(new BigDecimal(Math.nextDown(1.0)));
    System.out.printf("Error on round down %s \n", downError);
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
1 / 3 = 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 
3 * (1/3) = 1 
0.999999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375
Error on round up 5.5511151231257827021181583404541015625E-17 
Error on round down 5.5511151231257827021181583404541015625E-17
```

The result of the multiplication by three was exactly half way between 1.0 and the largest double that is less than 1.0. In that case, the round-to-even rule comes into play. The least significant bit of the significand for 1.0 is zero, so 1.0 is the answer. The round-to-even rule does tend to favor integers and other round numbers over their neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

0.333333 is already rounded.

double are stored in three parts, sign, exponent and fraction

[image: double]

in fact, 1/3 is stored as [0x3FD5555555555555](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=3FD5555555555555), and does not equal 0.333333 but 3.33333333333333314829616256247E-1.

Even if it's rounded, it's accurate enough, so that this number*3 equals 1

Comment: is it stored as some sort of fraction? not a decimal?

Comment: As a fraction in base 2, hence a sum of negative powers of 2: 2^-2 + ...